# Javascript: If Statement containing functions not resolving

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hi I'm still new to javascript and I cannot understand why this if statement won't resolve

message is a variable string, take "!leve alc 35" as an example.

```
var leve = parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]);

var leves = function() {
  if (Number(leve) < 50) {
    [(message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
      round5(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ]; // Getting the lvls in question
    leves = leves.join("");
  } else {
    [(message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
      round2(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ]; // Getting the lvls in question
    leves = leves.join("");
  }
};
```

I expect this code to identify if the value at the end of the String(message) is greater than 49 (50+), and if so use the round 2 formula instead of the round 5 formula. I know its the if statement at fault as each line runs fine separately and returns my expected value. I've compared my if statement to that on W3Schools and I don't believe I'm missing anything. I placed my if statement within a function and this stopped the initial error I received on loading the script, but I'm now questioning if this is the issue?

EDIT

return function (this is a bot for discord):

```
case 'leve':
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
    message: leves 
    });
    break;
```

rounding formulas

```
  var round5 = function round5(x) {
    return Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5;
  };
  var round2 = function round2(x) {
    return Math.ceil((x+1) / 2) * 2;
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*won't resolve*"?

Comment: You don't have any return statement in your function

Comment: @CodeManiac Does it matter? The function is never called anyway.

Comment: what is *round 2 fromula*?

Comment: @melpomene apologies, I wish to return leves and it should equate my example to ALC40 due to the round5 function rounding up to nearest 5x.

Comment: @melpomene no it doesn't if not called :p

Comment: What do you mean by "*return leves*" and "*should equate*"?

Comment: `leves` refers to the variable bound to the function in the outer scope, then you try to reassign `leves` to the result of calling `join` on itself which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the call of the join on itself does still work as the else function still works outside the if statement, but the leves referring to a variable bound to the outer scope what do you mean please?

Comment: WTH are you doing with these array literals?

Comment: @RichardGoodman by the time the function is invoked, `leves` will been rebound to the function. FYI, never use W3Schools as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the splitted values and return a new string with a rounded value according to the value.

```js
const
    round5 = x => Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5,
    round2 = x => Math.ceil((x + 1) / 2) * 2,
    leves = message => {
        var [, string, value] = message.split(' ');
        value = +value < 50 ? round5(+value) : round2(+value);
        return [string.toUpperCase(), value].join("");
    };

console.log(leves('!leve alc 35'));
console.log(leves('!leve alc 54'));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work through my mess, this code works for the round 5 function but for some reason values above 50 aren't returning correctly, for "!leve alc 54" I would expect ALC56 but I see ALC542. It appears to be adding a 2 to the end of the initial value?

Comment: that was a problem by handing over a string and a following addition.

Comment: ahh i see it, the value needing the + to indicate it is a number right? thank you for your help, this is working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should be like this. Assumes "message" as a global variable

```
var leves = function() {
  if (Number(leve) < 50) {
    return [(message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
      round5(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ].join("");// Getting the lvls in question
    //leves = leves.join("");
  } else {
    return [(message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
      round2(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ].join(""); // Getting the lvls in question
    //leves = leves.join("");
  }
};
```

Comment: @Bergi no need to remove parenthesis, yes you are right comma will act as delimit array element

Comment: @Bergi It is working, i can't find any issues. see this fiddler link https://jsfiddle.net/SyamKumarD/nuey9j6c/2/

Comment: Oh you're right, I was totally confused by the unnecessary parenthesis around `message.split(' ')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you meant to write was

```
var leve = parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]);

if (Number(leve) < 50) {
    var leves = [
        (message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
        round5(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ]; // Getting the lvls in question
    leves = leves.join("");
} else {
    var leves = [
        (message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
        round2(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ]; // Getting the lvls in question
    leves = leves.join("");
}
```

No function, no expression-only statements that create array literals but do nothing with them, but rather assignments to the `leves` variable.

If you wanted to declare and assign `leves` only once, you could use the conditional operator:

```
var leve = parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]);

var leves = (Number(leve) < 50)
  ? [
        (message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
        round5(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ]
  : [
        (message.split(' ')[1]).toUpperCase(),
        round2(parseInt(message.split(' ')[2]))
    ];
leves = leves.join("");
```

But that's still a lot of duplication. I would recommend to write

```
var parts = message.split(' ');
var leve = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

leve = (leve < 50) ? round5(leve) : round2(leve);
var leves = parts[1].toUpperCase() + leve;
```